# How can I create a transparent image holder in django?

Tags: html, django, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create a transparent image holder in python. I then want to add images to the holder. When the image holder is display on a web page I want to see the images, but I want the holder to be transparent. Thus I will still be able to see the original page behind the image holder

My Code is as follows

```
def test_image():
    image_holder = PilImage.new('RGBA', (800, 200), (255, 0, 0, 0))
    test_image = PilImage.open('test_image.png')
    a_channel = PilImage.new('L', test_image.size, 255)
    test_image.putalpha(a_channel)
    image_holder.paste(test_image, (50, 100), test_image)
    image_holder.save('test_image_A.png')
    return test_image
```

If I view the image in a web page it works perfectly

```
<img src="my_imageA.png" width="800" height="232">
```

But if I pass the image through a django context, the image_holder appears as red

```
context['test_image'] = test_image()
```

What can I do?

Comment: any reason why you don't just apply CSS?

Comment: Don't know how!  Didn't kmow you could do it!

Comment: Are you trying to have a modal to pop up that holds images, where the images are opaque, but the rest of the modal is transparent, showing the page behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was converting the image to a JPEG to encode for JSON

```
def _encode_image(image):
    """Return image encoded to base64."""
    image = image.convert("RGB")
    io_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(io_buffer, format='JPEG')
    values = io_buffer.getvalue()
    encoded_image = ''.join(['data:image/jpg;base64,', base64.b64encode(values).decode()])
    return encoded_image
```

and, of course JPEG does not support an alpha channel. Should have been

```
def _encode_image(image):
    """Return image encoded to base64."""
    image = image.convert("RGBA")
    io_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(io_buffer, format='PNG')
    values = io_buffer.getvalue()
    encoded_image = ''.join(['data:image/jpg;base64,', base64.b64encode(values).decode()])
    return encoded_image
```

Note that in the question I had saved the image as *.png*. I hadn't thought the encoding was relevant at that point.